# References to "La jetée" in "12 Monkeys"

Tags: 12-monkeys, la-jetee, reference

In some scenes of [12 Monkeys](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114746/) Cole (Bruce Willis) wears a t-shirt with the word "Chris" very visible. This is an homage to Chris Marker, the french film director of ["La jetée"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056119/) in which the movie is based.

[image: Cole sitting on a bed with a letter]

Are there any other subtle references to "[La jetée](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_jet%C3%A9e)" in the movie?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should probably be knowing that the movie itself is inspired from La jetée.

If you have seen La jetée, you'd obviously notice that the movie is just a series of still frames with a narrator in the background. There is a scene in Twelve monkeys where Railly narrates a slide show about a insane soldier in World War I. And when Railly and Bruce Willis take refuge in a movie theater that happens to be showing Alfred Hitchcock's Vertigo (*an important influence on Chris Marker and La Jetee*)

Comment: Also, the fact that the film climaxes in the airport is not only a reference but a direct adaption of La jetée.

Comment: the strange eyewear of the scientists in 12 Monkeys echoes the weird sunglasses worn by their counterparts in La Jetee, including the guy in the cover shot