# Did Cole complete his mission or not?

Tags: plot-explanation, 12-monkeys

In *12 Monkeys* (1995), at the end of the movie, Cole is killed by a man in the airport. So did sending Cole into the past for a cure work or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What was the story of 12 monkeys really about?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38773/what-was-the-story-of-12-monkeys-really-about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending of 12 Monkeys implies heavily that they could not change time. By sending Cole back in time, they completed a circle. It's a predestination paradox.

Cole changed nothing. If anything, he allowed it to happen as history said it happened.

Cole did as best he could given the information and minimal help provided.

Comment: Yet, I don't think his mission ever was to actually *prevent* the virus, rather than gather enough information for it be cured *in the future*. And this mission he might very well have completed.

Comment: @Napoleon the only information he gave to the future about the virus was the phone call he makes. Which is what they already had, a half damaged voice mail recording. No new information is passed on.